# Is it possible to modify KeyboardEvent before webpage processes it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-events, browser-extension

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to re-map keyboard shortcut defined by a web application, because that would solve this issue: [Frustration over Shift+Space YouTube keyboard shortcut when creating subtitles](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/113660/16499).

So, I was thinking: would it be possible, for a Chrome/Mozilla/... extension to capture and modify `KeyboardEvent` (in this case, just clear the `Shift` modifier for space character) before the event is passed to the web application?

I was looking for such an extension but no success yet. Is it possible to do it, in principle?

**EDIT (response):** I am afraid dispatching new event won't have the desired effect, see this [wontfix bugreport](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=52408) and [a note here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent):

> Manually firing an event does not generate the default action
>   associated with that event. For example, manually firing a key event
>   does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input. In the
>   case of UI events, this is important for security reasons, as it
>   prevents scripts from simulating user actions that interact with the
>   browser itself.

So, it doesn't work for me to re-dispatch the same key without the Shift modifier (see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rzh1p5qn/2/).

Comment: Yes, you can re-emit another KeyboardEvent without the Shift key and preventDefault on the original one.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, could you please expand this to an answer, possibly with code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In principle an event listener on that input could stop propagation of the event when that key combination is pressed. The  shortcut listener is likely attached to the  window. Not sure what exact event or events they listen to though

Comment: @wOxxOm unfortunatelly it seems that re-dispatching an event is not working :( see the update.

Comment: If document.activeElement is an input or contentEditable you can use document.execCommand('insertText', false, event.char), also see @Aminadav's answer - you can use it if you [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm, I've been looking at the answers there but I cannot find how they run the injected script `before` the YouTube's scripts. I'd be grateful for more detailed answer..

Comment: Use `"run_at": "document_start"` in manifest.json for your content script.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can do many strange things. It is not recommended and it can make bugs, but you can do it, and it can work.

All you have to do it to replace `document.addEventListener` with
your function (Just keep a copy of the original function). For that you should add your script first on the page (before any other script attaches events).

Your function will have its own conditions and then execute the original function.

Your own function will register the user function, but you should wrap it in a condition that changes the event object.

You can add any condition, or change the event, before triggering the original handlers.

Comment: interesting idea, but how to get the script run before youtube's scripts?

Comment: Many ways. For example, you can set the script to execute at `document_start` -
 (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)